# IIS giving error Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, text-to-speech

I am trying to make a text to speech conversion software. The code is working as per expectation at visual studio 2008. However when I moved the project to IIS it gives error.

Below I am pasting the code and the error respectively

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SpeechLib;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void bttn_Speak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();
        SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags SpFlags = SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault;

        voice.Speak("hello", SpFlags);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Server Error in '/speech' Application.
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Source Error:


Line 18:         SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags SpFlags = SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault;
Line 19: 
Line 20:         voice.Speak("hello", SpFlags);
Line 21:     }
Line 22: }


Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\speech\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 20

Stack Trace:


[COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.]
   SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass.Speak(String Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags Flags) +0
   _Default.bttn_Speak_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\speech\Default.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

I am using windows 7 as operating system. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance for the help requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the speaker from IIS.  Even if you did, the voice would be generated *in the server room*, and not on the user's web page.